# Probability and Single Particle Partition function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I have a fundamental question in statistical mechanics that I can't wrap my head around.

When we speak about the probability of a SYSTEM being in macrostate with energy E we calculate this by:

$$ P(E) = \frac{e^{-\beta E}}{Z} $$

where Z is the partition function.

But if we zoom in and look at the probability of a specific particle being in a state with energy E can we still calculate this as:

$$ P(E) = \frac{e^{-\beta E}}{Z_1} $$

Where now Z1 is the single particle partition function?

What seems confusing to me is that this calculation of probability (with the partition function) stemmed from the fact that the probability for a specific macrostate (i.e. a specific energy) is proportional to the number of available microstates with that energy. But if we only have a single particle (and no degeneracy, which is reasonable) then each energy only corresponds to a single microstate. Then this reasoning with partition functions seems illogical to me.